# How to change an order of samples in Tukey's test in R?

Tags: r, anova, posthoc

**Problem**:
I would like to learn how can I change an order of samples for which Tukey's test in R calculates means and assign corresponding letters. Very simple example is below.

I played with *iris* data and have found that there are differences in Sepal.Length among different Species. Here is the boxplot:

[image]

I conducted an ANOVA test and have found that differences are statistically significant.

```
> fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)
> summary(aov(fit))

             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
Species       2  63.21  31.606   119.3 <2e-16 ***
Residuals   147  38.96   0.265                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Then I conducted Tukey's test and got following:

```
> library(agricolae)
> HSD.test(fit, "Species", group=T, console=T)

Study: fit ~ "Species"

HSD Test for Sepal.Length 

Mean Square Error:  0.2650082 

Species,  means

           Sepal.Length       std  r Min Max
setosa            5.006 0.3524897 50 4.3 5.8
versicolor        5.936 0.5161711 50 4.9 7.0
virginica         6.588 0.6358796 50 4.9 7.9

alpha: 0.05 ; Df Error: 147 
Critical Value of Studentized Range: 3.348424 

Honestly Significant Difference: 0.2437727 

Means with the same letter are not significantly different.

Groups, Treatments and means
a    virginica       6.588 
b    versicolor      5.936 
c    setosa          5.006
```

According the table of groups, HSD.test function sorts means into descending order and then assign letters. Thus, "virginica" have the largest mean, therefore it is the first in the table.

**Questions**: 
Is there any way to change the default sorting and assigning of letters?
Can I sort samples in ascending order of means and then assign letters. 
An expected output is following:

```
a setosa     5.006
b versicolor 5.936
c virginica  6.588
```

**Possible solution**: In package *multcomp* there are two functions which can do it working together:

1 - `glht` do Tukey's test

```
> an <- aov(fit)
> library(multcomp)
> glht(an, linfct = mcp(Species = "Tukey"))

         General Linear Hypotheses

    Multiple Comparisons of Means: Tukey Contrasts


    Linear Hypotheses:
                                Estimate
    versicolor - setosa == 0       0.930
    virginica - setosa == 0        1.582
    virginica - versicolor == 0    0.652
```

2 - `cld` can provide me with letters assigned to `Species` according levels of the factor `iris$Species`

```
> cld(glht(an, linfct = mcp(Species = "Tukey")))
    setosa versicolor  virginica 
       "a"        "b"        "c"
```

Unfortunately, `glht` function do not show another data which can be useful and needed for creating of barplot (means, std, p-values). Of course, I can do it separately with another special functions, or just use both `HSD.test` and `cld`. But I would prefer to solve a problem with sorting of means in `HSD.test` function and use only this one.

Comment: Even if you cannot add an image to your post, I believe you can add a link to an image on an imagesharing-site.

Comment: Thank you, eirikdaude.
Here is a boxplot of the data: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Zb44o.jpg

Comment: `TukeyHSD()` in the `stats` package will get you ascending-ordered means with `ordered=TRUE`, but doesn't assign letters...

Answer (score 2):

I notice it's a bit late to answer this question. However I ran into the exact same problem and like to share my solution as future reference. Hope it helps someday someone.

### first option

One could use `multcompLetters()` for example with the results from `TukeyHSD()`. However, this doesn't allow an arbitrary ordering of the result and is not so easy to use.

### second option

Since I needed an arbitrary order I wrote my own function, which takes a vector of letters like returned from `HSD.test` and swaps the letters in a way the result is nice. Meaning letters first in alphabet appearing first.

```
library(agricolae)
reorder<-function(inV){
  collapsed <- paste(inV,sep="",collapse = "")
  u <- unique(strsplit(collapsed,"")[[1]])
  if(length(u)<2){
    return(inV)
  }
  u <- u[order(u)]
  m <- matrix(nrow=NROW(inV),ncol=length(u))
  m[]<-F
  for(i in 1:length(inV)){
    s <- strsplit(inV[i],"")[[1]]
    index <- match(s,u)
    m[i,index] <- T
  }
  for(i in 1:(length(u)-1)){
    firstColT <- match(T,m[,i])[1] #first row with true in current column
    firstT <- match(T,rowSums(m[,i:length(u)] > 0))[1] #first row with true in rest
    if(firstT < firstColT){
      colT <- match(T,m[firstT,i:length(u)])[1]
      colT <- colT + i - 1 #correct index for leftout columns in match
      tmp <- m[,colT]
      m[,colT] <- m[,i]
      m[,i] <- tmp
    }
  }
  res <- vector(mode = "character", length=length(trt))
  for(i in 1:length(inV)){
    l <- u[m[i,]]
    res[i] <- paste(l,sep="",collapse = "")
  }
  return(res)
}

fit <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)
a <- HSD.test(fit, "Species", group=T, console=F)$groups
a <- a[rev(rownames(a)),] #order the result the way you want
a$M <- reorder(as.character(a$M))
```

For the example it is a bit of an overkill but it should also work for more complicated cases.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to solve with multcompLetters() and TukeyHSD(). You should change the parameter "reversed"

```
library(multcompView)

fit <- aov(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)

tukey<-TukeyHSD(fit, ordered = T)
tukey_1<-multcompLetters2(Sepal.Length ~ Species,
                          tukey$Species[,"p adj"],
                          iris,reversed = T)
tukey_2<-multcompLetters2(Sepal.Length ~ Species,
                          tukey$Species[,"p adj"],
                          iris,reversed = F)
tukey_1
tukey_2
tapply(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Species, mean)
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, thanks for the function. It was what I was looking for. But I think that there is a mistake in

```
res <- vector(mode = "character", length=length(trt)),
```

it should be

```
res <- vector(mode = "character", length=length("trt"))
```